# sending linux log to sunos Syslog file

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, solaris

I would like to write a C program that can send a Log details from Linux to a remote SunoS server. The logs would add in the syslog file at the server side. I have tried some methods such as send() , sendto() etc. But could not perform the transfer. Anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *SE Unix & Linux provides support for Linux, and SunOS being the only OS you specifically mention is off-topic here*